# I have a SQL query that loops data

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to display certain record, but it is displaying extra data, for instance I have only 239 records in my database, but the query is displaying 356 records. Can anyone advice me on what I did wrong, I would really appreciate it. Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.branchid,
    t.occupancyid,
    t.wardnumber,
    t.bednumber,
    t.admissiondate,
    ti.patientname
FROM
    bedoccupancydetail t
JOIN 
    consultationheader ti ON t.occupancyid = ti.occupancyid
WHERE
    t.checkedout = '0'
```

Comment: Did you want to do a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I am not sure,, if it could work I wouldn't mind trying it

Comment: You have 2 tables in your query, which table has 239 records or are you saying there are 239 records in total in both tables? nb joins are cumulative and distinct is over all the selected columns.

Comment: The records are related,, the total data is 239. Just that I had the different columns on different tables.

Comment: Presumably, some bedoccupancydetails are associated with multiple occupancyids (or vice versa). So you haven't done anything wrong.

Comment: It might help if you published anonymised data to a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your feed back I just figured out where the problem is. Check below I explained it extensively. Again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There might not be any problem with your query, just it is how mysql (or any RDBMS) behaves. In your case in the two tables `bedoccupancydetail` and `consultationheader` are joined by `occupancyid` and it seems this columns is not unique and contains duplicate values, for each matching (duplicate) record it adds a row/record after joining.
Let's see the below example which I run at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'TOM');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,'TOM');

CREATE TABLE ABC(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Another text);

INSERT INTO ABC VALUES(1,'Tom', 'A');
INSERT INTO ABC VALUES(2,'Lucy', 'B');
INSERT INTO ABC VALUES(3,'TOM', 'C');
INSERT INTO ABC VALUES(4,'TOM', 'D');

COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT ABC.Name, NAMES.Name, ABC.Another
FROM NAMES
JOIN ABC on ABC.Name = NAMES.Name;
```

As you see each table has **4** rows but the result has **6** rows:

```
$sqlite3 database.sdb < main.sql
Tom|Tom|A
Lucy|Lucy|B
TOM|TOM|C
TOM|TOM|D
TOM|TOM|C
TOM|TOM|D
```

Comment: To exactly match the problem the select needs a DISTINCT

Comment: Okay so I figured out what went wrong and thank you so much for your feedback. I have realized that the person keying in the data used the same data on all rows but one. The wardnumber column has same persons but different number. I think the solution will be using the SELECT UNIQUE fx for the primary key.

Comment: @P.Salmon But in his query he might has some other fields which invalidates the effect disticts